# Validating URL Parameters in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-router, react-router-v4

I'd like to figure out a way to validate a Route path like this `/items/:id` in React Router v4. I want to check if this item exists in the database (thus requiring a Promise or async call) before proceeding to either render the `ItemPage` component or `Redirect` component to the login page. I've been trying to follow the pattern at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow but the validation does not require an async call. When I try to do something like

```
const ValidatedRoute = async ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    await param.isValid? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

I get `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).` How can I make an async validation of a `Route` param?

Answer (score 9):

Update: I tried two approaches.

Higher Order Components: I created 2 higher order components, `AuthenticatedRoute` and `ValidatedRoute`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

let AuthenticatedRoute = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!sessionStorage.jwt) {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: this.props.location }
      }}/>
    }
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

And

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

let ValidatedRoute = ComposedComponent => class extends Component {
  state = {
    isValid: true
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isValid: await this.props.validator(this.props.match.params.id)
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isValid) {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: this.props.redirect,
        state: { from: this.props.location }
      }}/>
    }
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default ValidatedRoute;
```

To use them, I wrapped the component that was being used for that route with `AuthenticatedRoute(ValidatedRoute(component))`. The advantage was that this allowed neat organization of authenticated vs. validated routes, but this had to be done in the components themselves, not in the router file. I just used regular `Router` there. So calling it in the route file looked like:

```
<Route exact path="/list/:id" render={(props) => <ProtectedComponent
              validator={Validator}
              redirect='/'
              {...props}
              />
            } />
```

The other option was to create a `PrivateRoute` component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  state = {
    authenticated: true,
    validated: true
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.validator) {
      this.setState({
        validated: await this.props.validator(this.props.computedMatch.params.id)
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.authenticate && !sessionStorage.jwt) {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: this.props.location }
      }}/>
    }

    if (!this.state.validated) {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: this.props.redirect,
        state: { from: this.props.location }
      }}/>
    }

    return <Route {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And it had to be called like:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/list/:id"
          authenticate={true}
          component={ProtectedComponent}
          validator={validator}
          redirect='/'
        />
```

Still feeling pretty anti-pattern and the React-Router-V4 docs aren't much with this. I went with HOCs since it felt a little more organized.